# flask-ngrok returns "Tunnel _________.ngrok.io not found" when running flask app via ngrok on Google Colab

Tags: python, flask, google-colaboratory, ngrok

I was running a "local" web app on Google Colab using flask-ngrok according to this article: [Flask on Google Colab](https://medium.com/@kshitijvijay271199/flask-on-google-colab-f6525986797b). It was working appropriately in the past but today I started to get the error: "Tunnel _______.ngrok.io not found" whenever I try to access the generated public URL by ngrok. Everything was unchanged since the last time when it still worked. I checked the [flask-ngrok package](https://pypi.org/project/flask-ngrok/0.0.25/), looks like the package version remains unchanged since 2018. Couldn't figure out what is going wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

```
!pip install flask-ngrok


from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)   #starts ngrok when the app is run

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "<h1>Running Flask on Google Colab!</h1>"

app.run()
```

Here's another similar article: [Running Python Flask Apps on Google Colab](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/running-python-flask-apps-google-colab-biranchi-nayak?articleId=6675616675573964801), there is a link to the  [full code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NN06tyHayRA447cMMI787p2NtdvwX_k5#scrollTo=B5TVfkO_9xpm) in colab where you can run it yourself. It now gives the same tunnel not found error too.

Comment: Same problem here. No code was changed and it stopped working. It was fine for months. I suspect that perhaps Colab is closing these sessions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tunnel not found error Pyngrok streamlit collab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65966425/tunnel-not-found-error-pyngrok-streamlit-collab)

Answer (score 1):

There was an inadvertent block put in place by the ngrok engineering team for the Google Colab environment due to a new tweak to the abuse prevention system.

It's since been rolled back so you shouldn't see this `""Tunnel _______.ngrok.io not found"` from within Google Colab anymore (hopefully).